# In pandas, how can I create a new MultiIndex levels based on another one?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

For instance, I have a multiIndex already which is datetime and row number, but I want to round the datetime to the nearest minute and use that as a new level on the MultiIndex.

Comment: Please post a part of your dataframe and the desired output. My imagination is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

This could do:

```py
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( [(round_to_minute(dt), row_number) for dt, row_number in df.index.values])
```

where `round_to_minute` your datetime rounding function.

```py
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( [(round_to_minute(dt), row_number) for dt, row_number in df.index.to_numpy()])
```

or

```py
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( [(round_to_minute(dt), row_number) for dt, row_number in df.index])
```

can work too.

Comment: .values not recommended anymore. I cant downvote yet but I will try to

Comment: @athing recommended? What do you mean? One can use `to_numpy()` or `values.tolist()` if preferred.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.values.html my downvote reason is you dont explain the code you write this is almost a code only answer which I dont think helps the asker who didnt show any attemmpt whatsoever anyway (i cant dovnote yet due to reputation) nothing personal